# Visual C++ browse information

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, browse-information

I am trying to figure out what the **browse information** (`.sbr` files) is used for but find only references how to create it. So what is it for?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/12/18/intellisense-history-part-1.aspx) *(Visual C++ Team Blog: IntelliSense History, Part 1)*

> Capturing information about a C or C++
>   program’s structure has been around
>   for a very long time in Microsoft’s
>   products.  Preceding even Visual C++
>   1.0, the compiler supported generating program information through .SBR and
>   .BSC files.  (Note:  The compiler in
>   Visual C++ 1.0 was already version 8,
>   so the command line tools had been
>   around a while already.)  **The SBR
>   files contain reference and definition
>   information for a single translation
>   unit that the compiler generates as it
>   compiles**.  These SBR files are
>   combined in a later step using the
>   BSCMAKE tool to generate a BSC file. 
>   This file can then be used to look at
>   many different aspects of a program: 
>   reference, definitions, caller-callee
>   graphs, macros, etc.

Comment: Great article!!! So if I use Visual Assist can I turn off "browse information" (the code base is pretty big - more than 1M LOC)?

Comment: I turn this off always, even without Visual Assist.

Answer (score 3):

`.sbr` is pretty much Visual Studio's `ctags` - an index of symbols with backreferences to the source. When available, it's used by "Find Symbol" and other similar tools. It's more accurate than the built-in VS parser, because C++ can be tricky, and the real compiler can do a better job (though that [is not quite true](http://blogs.msdn.com/pminaev/archive/2009/06/09/c-intellisense-in-vs2010.aspx) in VS2010 anymore).

Answer (score 2):

At one time browse info drove the "Go to definition" engine, but that has been reworked in later version of Visual C++. Some third-party tools still use browse info (can't remember for sure, but I think one of Rational's tools does) to cross-reference code.

I always disable it, to shorten build times.

Comment: Isn't it disabled by default?

Comment: @Pavel: Could be that it is. I tend to run into it in legacy codebases where it has either been on by default in earlier VS versions, or people have enabled it as an attempt to improve IntelliSense.